# Use if statement in apply to create new variable

Tags: r, for-loop, sapply

I have a data.frame with ID number, Sex and age. I want to create column with a score based on sex and age. First I want to assign a score of 1 to all males, `M`

```
ID   Sex   Age   sex_score
1    M     72    1
2    M     65    1
3    F     55    0
```

I have tried with both a `for` loop and with `sapply` but I'm still a beginner and don't really know how to use these. These are my attempts:

`sex_score <- for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {if (df$Sex == "M") {1} else {0}}`
I get the warnings

```
In if (eligible$Sex == "M") {... :
the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

I've also tried
`Sex_score <-  sapply(df,function(x)if (df$Sex == "M") {1} else {0})`
I get the same warnings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I advise you to use package `tidyverse`. If your data.frame is named `df` (please don't name your data.frame `data.frame`) try:

```r
df %>%
  mutate(sex_score = as.integer(Sex == "M"))
```

Comment: Thank you that's a simple solution. No, don't worry my data.frame  isn't called `data.frame`! It would be helpful as a learner to know how you might do this sort of thing with a `for` loop or `sapply`

Comment: Two possibilities: `df$Score <- sapply(df$Sex, function(i) as.numeric(i == "Male"))` or `for (i in 1:nrow(df)) { df$Score[i] <- as.numeric(df$Sex[i] == "Male") }`. But try to avoid `for`-loops, there are often better ways of getting the job done.

Comment: Thanks again. I've also created an `age_score` variable. For this I used a `for` loop: `for (i in 1:nrow(eligible)) {if (eligible$Age[i] > 80) {eligible$age_score[i] = 6} 
  else if (eligible$Age[i] > 70) {eligible$age_score[i] = 4} 
  else if (eligible$Age[i] > 60) {eligible$age_score[i] = 2} 
  else if (eligible$Age[i] >50) {eligible$age_score[i] =1} 
  else {eligible$age_score[i] = 0}}` Is there an alternative to the `for` loop here?

Comment: With `dplyr` it's easy to do that: `eligible %>% mutate(age_score = case_when(Age > 80 ~ 6, Age > 70 ~ 4, Age > 60 ~ 2, Age > 50 ~ 1, TRUE     ~ 0))`. The `mutate`-function creates the new variable. `case_when` is a better version for nested `if-else`-statements, the left hand side of `~` gives the condition, the right hand side the value.

Comment: Take a look at [R for Data Science](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/). This gives a good introduction into working with R.

Comment: Thanks I've used `case_when` to create a final variable: `eligible = eligible%>%
  mutate(Risk_Score = (sex_score + age_score))%>%   mutate(Risk_Category = case_when(Risk_Score <3 ~ "Low",  Risk_Score >= 3 & Risk_Score <=5 ~ "Medium",  Risk_Score >5 ~ "High"))`

Comment: You don't have to use two `mutate`-functions, just replace `)%>%   mutate(` with `,`.

Answer (score 3):

Data:

```
df <- data.frame(
  Sex = c("Male", "Male", "Female")
)
```

Solution:

```
df$Score <- ifelse(df$Sex=="Male", 1, 0)
```

Result:

```
df
     Sex Score
1   Male     1
2   Male     1
3 Female     0
```